# Building Spark1.2.0 codebase with IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark

I download the Spark1.2.0 codebase from Git, and import it into Intellij Idea as Maven Project.
Then I do Maven Install against the root module in the Maven Projects view.

After a long time of building, all the modules are built successfully. But when I run the LocalPi in IntellijIdea, the compiling errors start to emerge:
1. the EventBatch and SparkFlumeProtocol class are not generated,they should be in 
org.apache.spark.streaming.flume.sink package.
2. There are a couple of error in CodeGenerator.scala, complaining q is a member of StringContext.

I have tried many time to fix these issues, but no luck.

Comment: Is there someone that encounter this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the "Generate Sources and Update Folders For All Projects" button in the "Maven Projects" tool window to manually generate these sources.

View -> Tool Windows -> Maven Projects

You may also right click on Spark Project External Flume Sink and click Generate Sources and Update Folders.